# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in VBA/SOAP

Tags: vba, excel, soap

I have a requirement to create a SOAP request from Excel/VBA. Forgive some of my terminology as I am fairly new to this process.

In the Header of the SOAP request there are 2 "sections". *UserAuth* and *CallBackAuth*. And then then under soap body there is *retrieve*.

After creating my construct of the envelope string in VBA and sending I was initially receiving errors that were obvious authentication errors. Once I used the correct name and password those errors went away so I know I am on the right track as far as the settings for the process.

Now I cannot get past the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." How would one troubleshoot this error? This seems to be a standard error you would see in SQL which I am very familiar with but with my limited knowledge here it doesn't make sense.

I have tried all combinations that I can think of for these placeholders to no avail.

Adding snippets from the envelope construct where I believe the issue to be?

```
        sEnv = sEnv & "<UserAuth xmlns=""http://targetsite.com/webservices"">"
            sEnv = sEnv & "<UserName>TEST</UserName>"           '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<Password>TEST1234</Password>"     '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<SID>1234567</SID>"            '***Need INT
           sEnv = sEnv & "<PID>1234566</PID>"              '***Need INT
            sEnv = sEnv & "<IUser></IUser>"       '***Need String
        sEnv = sEnv & "</UserAuth>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<CallBackAuth xmlns=""http://realpage.com/webservices"">"
            sEnv = sEnv & "<App></App>"                       '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<SID>""111""</SID>"           '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<SID>4242423</SID>"                      '***Need INT
            sEnv = sEnv & "<PID>4242422</PID>"                  '***Need INT
            sEnv = sEnv & "<EncryptionKey>""TESTID""</EncryptionKey>"  '***Need String
        sEnv = sEnv & "</CallBackAuthInfo>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Header>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Body>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<RetrieveData xmlns=""http://targetsite.com/webservices"">"
            sEnv = sEnv & "<after>""30""</after>" '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<balance>""0.00""</balance>"   '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<sID>""ALL""</sID>"               '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<Fextract>""1/1/1900""</Fextract>"   '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<Textract>""10/01/2017""</TextractTo>"       '***Need String
            sEnv = sEnv & "<ErroronData>true</ErroronData>"    '***Need BOOLEAN
        sEnv = sEnv & "</RetrieveData>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"
```

Comment: There's nothing specific in your question (no code, no sample XML, no information about the back-end of the SOAP service) so it's almost impossible to guess what the problem is.  "varchar" sounds like it could be database-related but that's it.

Comment: I was unsure what information to make this more descriptive. Let me edit with some of the code where placeholders are required.. These seem to be where my issue is stemming from

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: I don't think you need quotes around the string values.  Also - you have two SID tags, one numeric and the other text - that seems pretty odd since there's nothing to distinguish one from the other.

Comment: @Tim Williams ... This seems to have worked! Thanks for your help. The extra SID tag was because I was trying to abbreviate things for the post. They are different in the actual code. Feel free to add as an answer if you want me to give you some credit?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need quotes around the string values.

Also - you have two SID tags, one numeric and the other text - that seems pretty odd since there's nothing to distinguish one from the other.